# Emulation of MMU accessing the contents of the registers

Tags: java, object-oriented

I'm having a play around with emulating a simple old CPU.

I've set the structure up, so far anyway, as follows:

The device is the main and creates an instance of the CPU. The CPU then creates instances of the registers, clocks and [MMU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit).

I'm in the position where the MMU needs to access the contents of the registers, how to do this? I figure I could probably bodge something together by passing the entire register object to the MMU when it's called but that seems unwieldy.

The other thing I thought to do would be to initialise the MMU with the register object in the constructor. If I'm not mistaken that will still reference the same object? Meaning any changes I do to the registers in the MMU will affect the whole system?

Comment: No reason why passing an instance of the register class wouldn't suffice, since you're always passing a reference, not a copy.  However, if speed is important, you may reorganize the code to prevent superfluous calls, but you'd sacrifice good program structure.

Comment: Great, I'll continue down that route then. I'm trying to build it slowly and with good practice as I go vs hacking it together like I normally do.

Comment: If the CPU's responsible for managing the registers, wouldn't it make sense to ask the CPU for the register contents?

Comment: @TMN, the MMU (Memory management unit) is able to talk to the registers directly. I've passed an instance of the registers during the startup which allows the MMU to do it's job

Comment: @Cabe6403 It looks like you are having confusions between object-oriented programming and hardware design. I'm afraid these two don't have much in common.

Answer (score 1):

> but that seems unwieldy

Nope, that is exactly how it should be done. You need an argument for a method? Pass the argument in. It's a core language feature! An example of how this may be useful is if the MMU loads from memory where the pointer is a value in the register- this may be any register. Simply pass in the appropriate register as a method argument.

Constructor arguments shouldn't really be used for random dependencies; they should only be used for things where the class fundamentally cannot exist or make sense without them.

Fundamentally, a large proportion of the terrible mistakes and design people make is just because they hate passing in parameters. But really, *the other alternatives are worse*. They just hurt a lot more in the long term and seem easy in the short term. It's by far the best thing to just pass the parameter in.

Answer (score 0):

The second part of your question reads like the classic reference versus copy issue with objects. If you initialise your MMU class with a reference to the registers then that reference points to the true register object (think of a reference as an automatically dereferenced pointer). If you copy the register object in your constructor then that's all you have - a snapshot copy of the state at the time of construction.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the CPU has an "inner piece" that has registers, executes instructions, etc. The only communication between "inner piece" and things outside of it are "read requests" and "write requests". Nothing outside the "inner piece" has any access to the inner piece's registers, execution units, etc.

If there is no MMU, then the "read requests" and "write requests" that are issued by the "inner piece" refer to physical addresses (e.g. which location is being read/written in actual RAM).

If there is an MMU, then it sits between the "inner piece" and the other stuff outside the "inner piece" (the RAM controller, etc), and modifies the addresses in "read requests" and "writes requests" in some way. In this case, the read/write requests from the "inner piece" are virtual addresses, and the MMU (outside the "inner piece") converts them into physical addresses.

Like everything outside the "inner piece", the MMU has no access to the registers and no reason to ever want access to the registers.

*Note: For a practical system things get more complex - e.g. multiple different types of address spaces (IO ports, PCI configuration space, etc), devices (and their registers) mapped into address space/s in various ways, various types of caches in various places, and things that act a little like network/packet routers (PCI bridges), etc. As the complexity increases it tends to be better to think of the system as a kind of network, where you have independent pieces connected by buses and/or links, and where each independent piece sends request packets to other pieces, responds to packets received from other pieces and sends reply packets back to other pieces. For the same reason, for a more realistic model in software, it would be better to use (e.g.) a "one thread per independent piece" approach where threads send messages (or packets in a literal "UDP/IP packets" sense) to each other. Essentially, it would be better to use the actor model and not OOP.*